# Linking my Dynamic Link Library to my CPP executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, dll, cmake

I'm using CLion with cmake.

I want to link my dll to my c++ project in `cmakelists.txt` but I don't know how to do that.

I have searched a lot but I didn't find any solution.

---

1. I have published a dll by visual studio in c++ which I want to link to my cmake project.

   - the project name and output name is `Benchmark` -> `Benchmark.dll`

here is the code: **`module.hpp`**

```
#pragma once
#ifdef CFAMILY_EXPORTS
#define CFAMILY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CFAMILY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point tpoint;
typedef std::chrono::seconds secs;
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds millis;
typedef std::chrono::microseconds micros;
typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds nanos;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
const auto tnow = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

extern "C" {
    CFAMILY_API void ResetTimer();
    CFAMILY_API void StartTimer();
    CFAMILY_API void FinishTimer();
    CFAMILY_API long long GetTimer();
    CFAMILY_API long long GetTimerMillis();
    CFAMILY_API long long GetTimerMicros();
    CFAMILY_API long long GetTimerNanos();
}
```

**`module.cpp`**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "module.hpp"

static auto start_time = tpoint();
static auto end_time = tpoint();

void ResetTimer()
{
    start_time = tpoint();
    end_time = tpoint();
}

void StartTimer() { start_time = tnow(); }

void FinishTimer() { end_time = tnow(); }

long long GetTimer() { return duration_cast<secs>(end_time - start_time).count(); }

long long GetTimerMillis() { return duration_cast<millis>(end_time - start_time).count(); }

long long GetTimerMicros() { return duration_cast<micros>(end_time - start_time).count(); }

long long GetTimerNanos() { return duration_cast<nanos>(end_time - start_time).count(); }
```

2. then in my project in clion I want to use it:**`main.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
// include my benchmark.dll here and use its methods

int main() {
    // StartTimer(); in dll
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) continue;
    // FinishTimer(); in dll
    // cout << GetTimerNanos() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**`cmakelists.txt`**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(SpeedTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(SpeedTest main.cpp)

find_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    NAMES Benchmark
    HINTS "D:\\VS Projects\\BenchmarkLibrary\\C-Family\\Release-output\\x64")
```

Comment: `find_library` only searches for the library file. For link with the library you still need `target_link_libraries(SpeedTest ${${PROJECT_NAME}})`. So, what **exactly** is not working? Do you have an error message?

Comment: The whole problem is divided into two things: **first** how to add a reference to my dll? **second** how to use and call dll functions inside the `main.cpp`. Thanks

Comment: "how to add a reference to my dll?" - Do you ask about how to **link** with your library? If yes, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) and answers for it. (For link with the shared library on Windows you need to have the **import** file (`.lib`). "how to use and call dll functions inside the `main.cpp`" - Just `#include <module.h>` and call functions defined in the header. For help `#include`  to find you header file specify include directories with `include_directories` or `target_include_directories` command.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. But that's static linking. I want dynamic linking at the run time. Is it possible?

Comment: `.lib` file accompanies both static and dynamic linkage. Just google for what import file means for dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the absolute directory of the `.dll` is `"D:\\VS Projects\\BenchmarkLibrary\\C-Family\\Release-output\\x64"`, then you just need to add the following instead of `find_library` statement. it just searches for the library as the comment said.

```
target_link_directories(SpeedTest 
    PRIVATE
    "D:\\VS Projects\\BenchmarkLibrary\\C-Family\\Release-output\\x64"
)
target_link_libraries(SpeedTest PRIVATE Benchmark)
```

---

**Update**:

To call a function, use the header associated with your lib. include it using the absolute directory or edit your `CMakeLists.txt` file to add that directory and then use the name of the header i.e in your `module.hpp`, use `#include"someHeader.hpp"`, then you can use the function declared in `someHeader.hpp`

---

To include the directory of your header, modify your `CMakeLists.txt` to add

```
target_include_directories(SpeedTest PRIVATE "The dir. of the header")
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way like csharp that we use `DllImport`?

Comment: @MMD I don't know `C#` but you have said that r using `CMake` and `CLion` and I think this is the best way to do that with the tools u r using.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution that was about using `Libloaderapi.h` which is included in `windows.h`.

**But I prefer using the way that [@asmmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9638272/asmmo) said**

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long (__cdecl *long64F)();

typedef void (__cdecl *voidF)();

int main() {
    HMODULE hmodule = LoadLibraryA(R"(D:\VS Projects\BenchmarkLibrary\C-Family\Release-output\Win32\Benchmark.dll)");
    
    auto reset_timer = (voidF) GetProcAddress(hmodule, "ResetTimer");
    auto start_timer = (voidF) GetProcAddress(hmodule, "StartTimer");
    auto finish_timer = (voidF) GetProcAddress(hmodule, "FinishTimer");
    auto get_timer = (long64F) GetProcAddress(hmodule, "GetTimer");
    auto get_timer_millis = (long64F) GetProcAddress(hmodule, "GetTimerMillis");
    auto get_timer_micros = (long64F) GetProcAddress(hmodule, "GetTimerMicros");
    auto get_timer_nanos = (long64F) GetProcAddress(hmodule, "GetTimerNanos");
    
    cout << "for 1,000,000 times\n"
         << "---------------------" << endl;
    
    start_timer();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) continue;
    finish_timer();
    
    cout << "time passed in secs:\t" << get_timer() << endl;
    cout << "time passed in millis:\t" << get_timer_millis() << endl;
    cout << "time passed in micros:\t" << get_timer_micros() << endl;
    cout << "time passed in nanos:\t" << get_timer_nanos() << endl;
    reset_timer();
    
    FreeLibrary(hmodule);
    return 0;
}
```